# PHP on find the array with two keys equal to two values ​in the array and remove it from the array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm developing a shopping cart. I keep the basket in one session. I can add the product to the cart. But I don't know how to remove product line from basket session.

Session structure; The session holds an array and the product arrays in it. I want to access the array I want to remove with two keys.

```
//Create basket session
$_SESSION['basket'] = [];

//Add a Product
$productArray = ['prodID' => '1', 'quantity' => '3'];
$_SESSION['basket'][] = $productArray;

//Post method comes with two variables (keys).
$prodID = $_POST['prodID'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

//How can I remove the array with keys equal to $prodID and $quantity within the session ?
```

Comment: You could set the product id as the key in the basket array: `$_SESSON['basket'][1337] = ['prodID' => 1337, 'quantity' => 3]`. Then you can always access that specific row (since they are set on product id) by doing: `$_SESSION['basket'][$prodID]`

Comment: I think this is an attractive solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First since your prodID should be unique in the session you can set it as the `basket` key

```
//Create basket session
$_SESSION['basket'] = [];

//Add a Product
$productArray = ['prodID' => '1', 'quantity' => '3'];
$_SESSION['basket'][$productArray['prodID']] = $productArray;

//Post method comes with two variables (keys).
$prodID = $_POST['prodID'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

//How can I remove the array with keys equal to $prodID and $quantity within the session ?
//Now you only need to update / replace the quantity here.
```